# debugging with netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm running netbeans under mac os x. When I debug it is terribly slow and often crashes. Has anyone else found the same issue with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving it a larger amount of memory:

http://gapes.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/tuning-jvm-switches-for-performance/